# World Weather Online - Not able to retrieve information from <request>

Tags: c#, api, xml-serialization, windows-phone, weather-api

I am new to Windows Phone development, recently started to try to create a weather app, I am using API from World Weather Online (http://www.worldweatheronline.com/).

I retrieved the below sample data from the web site (http://free.worldweatheronline.com/feed/weather.ashx?q=paris&format=xml&num_of_days=5&key=xxxxxxxx):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<data>
  <request>
    <type>City</type>
    <query>Paris, France</query>
  </request>
  <current_condition>
    .......
  </current_condition>
  <weather>
    .......
  </weather>
  <weather>
    .......
  </weather>
</data>
```

I try to parse the xml and put them in a data class in C#.  Below is my code:

```
XDocument doc = XDocument.Parse(e.Result);
var data1 = from q in doc.Descendants("result")
            select new RequestData
            {
               type = (string)q.Element("type"),
               query = (string)q.Element("query")
            }
```

This is my data class:

```
public class RequestData
{
  public string type {get; set;}
  public string query {get; set;}
}
```

But after the above codes executed, there is no error (good), but there is no data from the `data1`.
I tried for `doc.Descendants("current_condition)` and `doc.Descendants("weather")` and I am able to get the data into the `data1`, only the `doc.Descendants("result")` didn't give me any result.

Anyone know why? 
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad, it's my own mistake, it should be "request", not "result".

It should be

```
doc.Descendants("request")
```

Not

```
doc.Descendants("result")
```